# WSL Debian scrolls down automatically when typing

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have install WSL and i am using Debian. Every time i clear the screen and start typing from the "top" of the console WSL will for some reason scroll down  by about 50 lines or so. If i scroll back to the top of the console and type again it will do the same thing.

The only way i can use WSL is if i hit enter above 50 times until there is about 50 lines or so on the screen then it will stop this scrolling nonsense... Has anyone seen this before? If so how did you fix it?

Comment: Type `clear;clear` instead of one `clear`.

Comment: wow. that worked... what is the idea behind that? Why do i have to do that?

Comment: @Biswapriyo you can add your comment as an answer with the explanation that matt is asking

Comment: He dosnt know it, probably copy pasted from somewhere, people are suggesting to use `clear -x` as it won't clear the scroll buffer, you can learn more about it by visiting `man clear`,

Comment: BTW `clear -x` doesn't work either, it keeps scrolling down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your .bashrc:

```
# Fix 'clear' scrolling issues
alias clear='clear -x'
```

Source: https://github.com/WhitewaterFoundry/pengwin-base/blob/a19d8330d6cbb4aa8f3b3b5cda4cd41770a4d18b/profile.d/00-pengwin.sh#L10

Pengwin

Regards

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 0):

You would do the command `clear -x` every time you want to clear the screen or add `alias clear='clear -x'` to your aliases in the .bashrc file. logout and login again  for the changes to take effect.